# What is the most important component for the airtightness of a room?

Tags: insulation, uk, vapor-barrier, building-regulations, draft

[image]

I have looked at the UK building regulations and it says that timberframe cavities should be airtight to a minimum of 0.6 changes. This is for new builds, not renovations which is my case.

Looking online this is normally achieved with several things:

- Vapor barrier membrane fitted correctly
- Good timberframee construction
- Insulation (PIR or Glasswool)
- Seals (tape or foam)

As a DIYer who might make mistakes.

What should be the focus when building an internal studwork to make sure it is not too draughty?

Do I just get all the components fitted well and then focus on the vapor barrier membrane?

Also - is thermal (foil) tape better than expanding foam for sealing joints in insulation boards (PIR)? The internet does not provide a conclusive answer.

Comment: Expanding foam is horrible stuff for a host of reasons, so the answer is most likely "yes".

Comment: For a *room* that's the inside of the envelope: the paint on the wall. For the entire structure, that's air-sealing, which is spray foam *or go home*. For studwork: caulk any laminated members. add insulation anywhere the spray foam guys won't be able to get to, like where four corners of four rooms meet and there's a 4"x4" dead zone in there.

Comment: In the UK we use expanding foam for sealing around a window frame, not sure what alternative there is apart from layers and layers of mastic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If building to certain standards then the use of expanding foam is not allowed. Built to those standards...

So we used a wood based insulation with the same heat retaining properties as other common insulation. Actually the wood based insulation was the same price but much easier to handle with less dust and much less irritation.

So, Fitting the vapour barrier is most important - think of it this way: if you turn the building upside down, will it hold water?

Comment: As in you're not allowed to use expanding foam to seal gaps around windows, timber, etc?

Comment: @tomaytotomato that is what “not allowed” means. The vapour barrier is sealed to the window frame anyway.